# Neo4j duplicate input id exception

Tags: neo4j

I am new to neo4j and I am trying to construct bitcoin transaction graph using it. I am following this link [behas/bitcoingraph](https://github.com/behas/bitcoingraph) to do so, I came across the neo4j import command to create a database

```
$NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j-import --into $NEO4J_HOME/data/graph.db \ 
  --nodes:Block blocks_header.csv,blocks.csv \ 
  --nodes:Transaction transactions_header.csv,transactions.csv \
  --nodes:Output outputs_header.csv,outputs.csv \  .......
```

After executing the above command I encountered an error

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.DuplicateInputIdException: Id '00000000f079868ed92cd4e7b7f50a5f8a2bb459ab957dd5402af7be7bd8ea6b' is defined more than once in Block, at least at /home/nikhil/Desktop/Thesis/bitcoingraph/blocks_0_1000/blocks.csv:409 and /home/nikhil/Desktop/Thesis/bitcoingraph/blocks_0_1000/blocks.csv:1410
```

Here is the block_header. csv

```
hash:ID(Block),height:int,timestamp:int
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? I read there is a solution available in id-spaces but I am not quiet sure how to use it. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [--skip-duplicate-nodes](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/import/command-line-usage/#import-tool-option-skip-duplicate-nodes) flag will skip import of nodes with the same ID instead of aborting the import.

For example:

```
$NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j-import --into $NEO4J_HOME/data/graph.db \ 
  --nodes:Block blocks_header.csv,blocks.csv --skip-duplicate-nodes \ 
  --nodes:Transaction transactions_header.csv,transactions.csv \
  --nodes:Output outputs_header.csv,outputs.csv \  .......
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Your question does not show that flag being used.

Comment: What I mean to say is that how do you use this flag thing, if you could say an example, I am completely new to neo4j so I am not sure how to use a flag

Comment: You just add it to your existing `neo4j-import` command line. See my updated answer.